# Is it true for solving differential equations by getting constant coefficient matrix with magnus expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The magnus expansion is given in detail
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion. While implementing magnus expansion to differential equations we have an iteration formula as follows 
$$Y'(t) = A(t)Y(t) $$
$$A_1 =A(t_n + h(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt3}{6})) $$
$$A_2 =A(t_n + h(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{6})) $$
$$ \sigma = \frac{1}{2}h[A_1+A_2] - \frac{\sqrt3}{12}h^2[A_1,A_2] + \frac{1}{80}h^3[A_1-A_2,[A_1,A_2]]  $$
$$Y_{n+1} = e^\sigma Y_n$$

where $[.,.]$ is Lie bracket. My question is that when i get $A$ matrix with only constants, is it true for this iteration formula ? For instance;

$$A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
  -100 & 1  \\
  1 & -1000 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

or every time must we get variable coefficients matrix? For instance;

$$A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
  -100t & 1  \\
  1 & -1000 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magnus expansion requires $\large A\left(t\right)A\left(t'\right) = A\left(t'\right)A\left(t\right)\,,\quad\forall\ t,t'$.

Comment: This situation always holds when $A(t)$ is constant coefficient matrix. So, can we solve ODE's by using magnus expansion with constant coefficient matrix?

Comment: I agree. Thanks.

Comment: @Amzoti thank you for answer. I found useful informations in this paper.

Comment: The use of the magnus expansion does not require that property at all.

Comment: The magnus expansion will technically solve the case with a constant $A$. However, there is no need to use it as it reduces to the ordinary matrix exponential if $A$ has no time dependence.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little bit confused about your ``iteration formula''. You mean that $Y_n=Y(t_n)$ and $t_1, ..., t_n$ are the points?

Well, If so then you do not need to ``insert'' any variables. In that case $Y=exp(tA)Y_0$ and that is exactly what your formula gives.

Comment: $Y_{n+1}$ is column vector for approximation values by getting with magnus expansion method. As you say above, my formula gives $Y_{n+1}=exp(hA)Y_n$. it is right, but it is giving very small errors with constant coefficient matrix. So is my approach is true or false for getting constant coefficient matrix for using magnus expansion to solve ODE's. ?

Comment: I believe your approach is correct, however i do not know rate of convergence for this method.